# CDI deferred injection is not working

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have an issue/problem with CDI in the next scenario:

Initializator is injected in the ServletContextListener. But after some other "steps" the method startup is invoked:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

   @Inject
   private Initializator initializator;

   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
         ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) event.getSource();
         String contextPath = ((ServletContext) event.getSource()).getContextPath();
         String serverName = servletContext.getInitParameter("SERVER_NAME");
         initializator.startup(serverName);
         System.out.println("ServletContext " + contextPath + " stated.");
   }

   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
         String contextPath = ((ServletContext) event.getSource()).getContextPath();
         System.out.println("ServletContext " + contextPath + " stopped.");
   }

}
```

The repository is successful injected in the initializator:

```
public class Initializator {

   @Inject
   private ChannelRepository repo;

   public String serverName;

   public void startup(String aServerName) {
         this.serverName = aServerName;
         initAll();
   }

   private void initAll() {
         List<Channel> channels = repo.getChannels();
         for (Channel channel : channels) {
                channel.start();
         }
   }

}
```

The repository retrieves the data and instantiates channels:

```
public class ChannelRepository {

   public List<Channel> getChannels() {
         List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<Channel>();
         // ...some db access via jdbc (or jpa)
         channels.add(new Channel("dummy", 8080));
         return channels;
   }
}
```

The channel needs a Logger:

```
public class Channel extends Thread {

   @Inject
   private Logger logger;

   public String name;
   public int port;

   public Channel(String aName, int aPort) {
         this.name = aName;
         this.port = aPort;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
         logger.log("Channel " + name + " is running in port " + port);
         // ...some other things to do
   }
}
```

How to avoid the manual creation of Channel instances?

The problem is done because the startup method in Initializator is invoked after the instance construction.

How to manage this type of "deferred" injections?

Comment: Your questions is very vague.  You don't typically use DI for data objects.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the manual creation of instances of Channel with

```
new Channel()
```

is fairly easy.

First we need a default constructor in class Channel and setters for channels attributes.

Then you must add this to your Channel Repo

```
@Inject
Instances<Channel> channelInstances;
```

and in your repo method change from

```
channels.add(new Channel("dummy", 8080));
```

to

```
Channel channel = channelInstances.get();
channel.setPort(8080);
channel.setName("dummy");
channels.add(channel);
```

A small hint:
If it is possible to do, don't let Channel extend Thread, but do the following

```
final Channel channel = channelInstances.get();
channel.setPort(8080);
channel.setName("dummy");

channels.add(new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    channel.doTheChannelStuff();
    channelInstances.destroy(channel);
  }
}
```

Why should you do this:

Under some circumstances a memory leak will be introduced when doing it in the way you are trying to use it. (Had a similiar issue at work) This has something to do with dependent scoped (default) dependencies and "manual" creation of new instances.